# How to send http post with socket connection

Tags: delphi, sockets, indy

I want to send `HTTP POST` command to a server with socket connection.

How can I do it with indy?

By the way, what is `HTTP`? and what is `Socket`? Is `IdHTTP` a socket?

Comment: Did you even googled these words? :|

Comment: I've already googled but not found the things that i want to know.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_socket

Comment: I want to make connection with socket, not http.

Comment: This is a lot of questions rolled up into one, which makes it difficult for people to answer.  Do some research on the terms you're curious about, and come back with specific parts you don't understand.

Comment: I want to open socket connection to a site, and post form with HTTP POST method, how to do?

Comment: HTTP is an application-layer protocol that runs on top of TCP/IP.  You create a TCP/IP socket an connect it to the desired server, then exchange HTTP messages back and forth as needed.  Indy's `TIdHTTP` handles all of those details for you. All you have to do is tell it where to connect and what to send.

Comment: @Remy: You are the only one who understand what I'm asking.

Comment: @CậuBéChănBò: then edit your question to [follow the correct rules](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist) for posting questions, and remove the unnecessary sub-questions, so it can then be reopened and answered.

Answer (score 1):

IdHTTP is not a socket, it´s a VCL component that implements a HTTP client. It´s indeed used to send HTTP commands to a web server, like the POST you want to perform.

Http: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol

Socket: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_socket

Post example: [Http Post with indy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10765661/http-post-with-indy)

Comment: I want to open socket connection to a site, and post form with HTTP POST method, how to do?