# Upload file with form data using Delphi Indy HTTP component

Tags: http, delphi, file-upload, indy, form-data

I want to replicate this part of Python code in Delphi using Indy:

```py
postdata = {'data': '{"data":{"xMode":0,"overrideOS":1,"messageId":"","vmProfileList":"11","submitType":"0","url":""},"filePriorityQ":"run_now" }'}
file_up = {'amas_filename':open('/home/samples/temp/vtest32.exe','r')}
file_upload_req=requests.post(url,postdata,files=file_up,headers=headers,verify=False)
```

I tried it like this:

```pascal
Params.AddFormField('data', '{"data":{"xMode": '+ xMode +',"analyzeAgain":1,"overrideOS":1,' +
                            '"vmProfileList":"' + DBProfileID.Value + '","submitType":0,"url":""}}');
Params.AddFile('amas_filename', DBTestFilePath.Value, GetMIMEType(DBTestFilePath.Value));
Params.Position := 0;
HTTP1.Request.ContentType := 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
JSON := HTTP1.Post(URL, Params);
```

but it gives me a HTTP error "HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request" and webserver says "Bad Request. Check input data and payload size". I know the data size is small enough.

This is the request from client and response from the server:

Client Side Says

```
POST /php/fileupload.php HTTP/1.0
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=--------031317093926335
Content-Length: 248815
VE-SDK-API: <<APIKEYWasHere>>
Host: Server_IP
Accept: application/vnd.ve.v1.0+json
Accept-Encoding: identity
User-Agent: Mozilla/3.0 - NBL
Cookie: PHPSESSID=<<Cookie_Was_Here>>

----------031317093926335
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="data"
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

{"data":{"xMode": 0,"analyzeAgain":1,"overrideOS":1,"vmProfileList":"2=
4","submitType":0,"url":""},"filePriorityQ":"run_now"}
----------031317093926335
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="amas_filename"; filename="Process.exe"
Content-Type: application/x-msdownload
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

MZP
<<FileDataWasHere>>
```

Server Service Says

```
HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, private,max-age=0
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, private,max-age=0
Pragma: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT
Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 89
Connection: close
Date: Mon, 13 Mar 2017 06:39:19 GMT
Server: Server FIPS

{"success":false,"errorMessage":"Bad Request. Check input data and payload size(<=200M)"}
```

What is wrong with my code?

PS: I have not done a file upload with form data before.

Comment: It is better to use `TIdMultipartFormDataStream` for form upload, check out my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10765661/http-post-with-indy/10765807#10765807).

Comment: @whosrdaddy the code is clearly already using `TIdMultipartFormDataStream`, by virtue of the fact that it is calling `AddFormField` and `AddFile`. However. Setting the `Request.ContentType` to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` is erroneous in that scenario, though `TIdHTTP` will ignore it since the `TIdMultiPartFormDataStream` will overwrite it.

Comment: t@RemyLebeau: I see, i was mislead due to the fact that he was setting the ContentType :)

Comment: @ErkanSen offhand, the code looks fine  (though the `ContentType` is wrong). Can you show what the actual HTTP request sent by `requeats.post()` looks like compared to the HTTP request sent by `TIdHTTP`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Next time you have trouble interacting with someone else's API, you should indicate what that API actually is so people have a chance to look up its documentation to see if anything is missing or wrong. In this case, you appear to be using the [McAfee Advanced Threat Defense API](https://kc.mcafee.com/resources/sites/MCAFEE/content/live/PRODUCT_DOCUMENTATION/25000/PD25810/en_US/ATD_344_API_Reference_Guide_revA_en_us.pdf).

A few things that stand out to me in your shown HTTP request:

1. `HTTP1.Request.ContentType := 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';`

   This is just plain wrong.  The correct content type is `multipart/form-data` instead.  However, `TIdHTTP` handles this for you when posting a `TIdMultipartFormDataStream`, so you don't need to assign a value to the `Request.ContentType` property at all, `TIdHTTP` will just overwrite it.  But that does not change the fact that there is a bug in your code nonetheless.
2. `Accept-Encoding: identity`

   This indicates to me that you are using an older version of Indy.  You should consider upgrading to a more recent version.  `TIdHTTP` no longer sends `identity` in the `Accept-Encoding` request header unless the `TIdHTTP.Request.AcceptEncoding` property contains other values, which is not the case here.  Some servers have trouble handling `Accept-Encoding: identity` when explicitly stated in a request, which is why it is no longer sent by default.
3. `Content-Type: text/plain`

   Your JSON field should have a `Content-Type` of `application/json`, or maybe even `application/vnd.ve.v1.0+json` in this API.  The default is `text/plain` when not specified otherwise.  `AddFormField()` has an `AContentType` parameter for this purpose.  The web server might be sensitive to that value.  JSON is also typically encoded using UTF-8, so you should indicate that as well.  `AddFormField()` has an `ACharset` parameter for that purpose.
4. `Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable`

   Your JSON string is being encoded using `quoted-printable`, which is normally fine for textual content in MIME, however not all web servers handle that in webform submissions, and it may not be appropriate for non-`text/...` media types, like JSON.  `AddFormField()` returns a `TIdFormDataField` object.  To disable the QP encoding, you can set the `TIdFormDataField.ContentTransfer` property to either `8bit` or `binary`.

That being said, try something more like this:

```pascal
Params.AddFormField('data', '{"data":{"xMode": ' + xMode + ',"analyzeAgain":1,"overrideOS":1,' +
                            '"vmProfileList":"' + DBProfileID.Value + '","submitType":0,"url":""}}',
                    'utf-8',
                    'application/json'
).ContentTransfer := '8bit';

// using GetMIMEType() to specify the ContentType is redundant as
// AddFile() already does that internally for you using Indy's own
// GetMIMETypeFromFile() function...
Params.AddFile('amas_filename', DBTestFilePath.Value);

JSON := HTTP1.Post(URL, Params);
```

If that still does not work for you, I suggest you contact McAfee directly for further help.

Comment: Thanks Remy. Your suggestion is solved the problem. (PS: I didn't think that API is importtant but  I will mention it if I need any help.)