# uploading photo using TIdMultipartFormDataStream and request payload data

Tags: http, delphi, photo

trying to upload picture using idhttp + idssl to change profile photo,,

this the request payload data :

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryhyy5Vlgv8YpwXz7K
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="profile_pic"; filename="profilepic.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg


------WebKitFormBoundaryhyy5Vlgv8YpwXz7K--
```

i know we should use TIdMultipartFormDataStream to include the photo but i dont know how, it supposed to be something like this `UploadParams.AddFile('photo', Edit11.Text);`

Comment: you can find an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10765807/800214) ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i know we should use TIdMultipartFormDataStream to include the photo

Yes.

> but i dont know how

`TIdMultipartFormDataStream` only has 3 methods for adding data fields:

- `AddFormField()` (which takes data as a `string` or a `TStream`)
- `AddObject()` (which is deprecated)
- `AddFile()`

Since you want to upload a file, it makes sense that you should use `AddFile()` (unless you open a `TStream` to the file, then you can use `AddFormField()` instead).

> it supposed to be something like this `UploadParams.AddFile('photo', Edit11.Text);`

Assuming `Edit11.Text` contains the full path and filename to the photo file that you want to upload, all you need to change is `'photo'` to `'profile_pic'`, since that is the `name` of the input field in your WebKit example:

```
UploadParams.AddFile('profile_pic', Edit11.Text);
```